# Strange behavior of signed APK

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded Android app on Google play store before. But today I am having difficulty with strange behavior with my 2nd app. This app's back end is on Windows VM.

The app when tested locally with production URLs is working fine but when I uploaded same app to Google play store it is working partially. i.e. With first API URL within app is giving me desired results.

But when I move forward to 2nd window of app I am getting **400 exception** on server. I again tested locally but it is working fine with same URL and entries.

This is my API request:

```
ValidateAPIRequest validateAPIRequest = new ValidateAPIRequest();
    validateAPIRequest.setPhoneNumber(Mobile_Number);
    validateAPIRequest.setOtp(otp);
    validateAPIRequest.setFcmToken(sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.FCM_ID,""));

GenericRequest<ValidateAPIResponse> IsValidOTP = new GenericRequest<>(Request.Method.POST, APIUrls.ValidateOTP(), ValidateAPIResponse.class, validateAPIRequest, new Response.Listener<ValidateAPIResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ValidateAPIResponse response) {

            if (progress.isShowing())
            {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN,response.getToken()).apply();
            editor.putBoolean(Constants.IsApproved, true).apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ValidateOTP.this, QRcodeReadingActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (progress.isShowing())
            {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError)
            {
                showNetworkErrorDialog(getString(R.string.No_Internet));
            }
            else
            {
                //This is getting called with Signed APK
                showErrorDialog(); 
            }


            Log.d(TAG,error.toString());
        }
    },null);

    queue.add(IsValidOTP);
}
```

Comment: Some code or your http requests would be helpful.

Comment: @Farasy this started when i started passing fcm token. Will post code soon.

Comment: @Farasy I added some code.